# How to highlight contents of parenthesis in Atom

Tags: package, atom-editor

I have just started to use Atom editor these days. Before that, I have used python IDLE. IDLE highlight the contents of parenthesis for us when we just created parenthesis. But, Atom does not.

Do you know any themes or packages to make it possible in Atom?

Comment: It should be built in: `bracket-matcher`. On my theme, it underlines the matching bracket in blue.

Comment: Yeah, I know my editor has bracket-matcher. But, I was not satisfied about that function. Cuz It is not clear enough for me compared with the time when I used to use python IDLE. But, thanks for tying to help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this selector: `atom-text-editor .bracket-matcher .region, :host .bracket-matcher .region` to highlight the brackets any way you want.

For example:

```
atom-text-editor .bracket-matcher .region,
:host .bracket-matcher .region {
    border-bottom: none;
    background: red;
}
```

This will make the brackets have a bright red highlight.

Comment: Thanks for this answer; it does what it's supposed to, and it can be used as-is by copying it into `styles.less`. However, you say "highlight the brackets any way you want" but nobody ever gives examples of how to make the brackets *themselves* a different color, or bold. Is this kind of customization not possible?

Comment: @JohnY Unfortunately, the highlights are in a different part of the HTML than the code you’re editing, so there’s no way to change the color of the text itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Material Theme, I'm using it and parenthesis is auto-created. Another choice is to install a package named BracketHighlighter.

Comment: How to get Material Theme ?